# Permitir determinados caracteres em um input text

Tags: javascript, regex

Possuo a seguinte expressão:

```
(/[^\d]/g, '')
```

Estou utilizando esta expressão em uma função JavaScript para que um `input type="text"` aceite somente números. O problema é que agora preciso que esta função também permita os caracteres `()+`.

Já fiz algumas pesquisas mas não achei nada muito didático, tendo em vista que comecei a mexer com expressões regulares há pouco tempo.

Como poderia habilitar estas caracteres através de expressões regulares?

Comment: Não seria o caso de só escapá-los? Ficaria algo assim: `(/[^\d\+\(\)]/g, '')`

Comment: Como vc está usando a regex? Porque `[^\d]` na verdade pega qualquer coisa que não seja número (e já permite os caracteres `(`, `)` e `+`, veja: https://regex101.com/r/AUKban/1/)

Comment: @FelipeAvelar Dentro de colchetes esses caracteres não precisam ser escapados: https://jsfiddle.net/8o5zhkL7/

Comment: @hkotsubo Irei conferir. Muito obrigado.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Acho que isso resolve: `[^\d()+]`

```js
const f = (ev) => {
if(ev.key.match(/[^\d()+]/)) {
ev.preventDefault();
}
}
```

```html
<input type="text" onkeypress="f(event)" />
```

Answer (score 2):

Uma solução é usar o [atributo `pattern`](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/input.html#the-pattern-attribute) do `input`:

```js
const campo = document.querySelector('#campo');

campo.addEventListener('input', () => {
  campo.setCustomValidity('');
  campo.checkValidity();
});

campo.addEventListener('invalid', () => {
    campo.setCustomValidity('O campo só pode ter números ou os caracteres ()+');
});
```

```css
/* deixar borda vermelha enquanto o campo for inválido */
input:invalid {
  border: red 1px solid;
}
```

```html
<form>
  <input id="campo" type="text" pattern="^[\d()+]+$" required />
  <input type="submit" value="ok">
</form>
```

O `pattern` recebe uma expressão regular dizendo exatamente o que ele pode ter. No caso, usei `^[\d()+]+$`.

Os [marcadores](https://www.regular-expressions.info/anchors.html) `^` e `$` são respectivamente o início e fim da string. Assim, eu garanto que o campo só vai ter o que eu determinar.

Em seguida tenho a [classe de caracteres](https://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html) `[\d()+]` que pega qualquer caractere que seja `\d` (um [atalho](https://www.regular-expressions.info/shorthand.html) que significa "dígito de `0` a `9`"), ou um `(`, ou `)`, ou `+`.

Logo depois temos o [quantificador](https://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html) `+`, que significa "uma ou mais ocorrências". Ou seja, o campo pode ter um ou mais caracteres, desde que eles correspondam a `[\d()+]`. Mas se quiser, pode trocar para [quantidades mais específicas](https://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html#limit):

- `[\d()+]{5,20}`: no mínimo 5 e no máximo 20 caracteres
- `[\d()+]{5,}`: no mínimo 5 caracteres, sem limite máximo
- `[\d()+]{5}`: exatamente 5 caracteres

Ajuste os valores de acordo com o que precisar.

---

A diferença desta solução para a [outra resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/413606/112052) é que esta não impede que o usuário digite caracteres inválidos. Ela apenas impede que o formulário seja submetido (e mostra uma mensagem caso ele tente submeter com dados inválidos - sendo que esta mensagem pode ser trocada com [`setCustomValidity`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Constraint_validation#element.setCustomValidity(message)), conforme mostrado acima).